# Orquestração web service

Tags: web-service, aplicação-web, rest, soap

Em muitos sites e artigos, é exibido o termo orquestração de serviços. Mas o que quer dizer orquestração de serviços e processos na terminologia de web services?

Answer (score 1):

**Orquestração**

Em SOA/BPM orquestração é a composição de serviços para criar um novo serviço ou para resolver uma tarefa de um processo de negócio. Neste caso, sempre há a figura de um ponto central. Um serviço ou uma atividade de negócio que coordena a chamada de outros serviços para compor uma função de maior granularidade. A orquestração de serviços é análoga a um método da orientação a objetos que faz chamadas de outros métodos.

**Coreografia**

A coreografia já é pré-determinada antes da sua execução. Por exemplo, quando um serviço é acionado e envia uma mensagem, outros serviços podem estar programados de ante-mão para receber ou não essa mensagem e dispararem outras ações. Chamamos este processo de evento. Serviços são acionados conforme a classe de eventos que ocorrem. Característica básica da arquitetura orientada a eventos. Em um middleware é possível atribuir esta característica através da criação de fluxos Publish/Subscribe.

[Fonte](http://sensedia.com/blog/soa/orquestracao-vs-coreografia/).

Existem diversas ferramentas que possibilitam esse tipo de trabalho, uma delas é o Workflow Foundation da MS. Quando se tem serviços atômicos, e se orquestra de acordo com a regra que você precisa desenvolver. É interessante pois quando você precisa alterar sua regra, se os seus serviços são atômicos, é muito fácil re-orquestra-los, mudar a ordem do negocio, sem gerar muito impacto ou até mesmo sem precisar codificar.